# To create valid dataset from train dataset (without using the model)

Tags: python-3.x

I have multiple folders name as train which contains multiple subfolders 0607130001,060713002....... (493 folders), each folder contains 50 files.
I want to create folders containing same name and move last 20 files from each of the subfolders to new created folder

Comment: Can you create an example of your folder structure and desired output?

Comment: train                                                  
     0607130001/0607130001-1.png...0607130001-50.png

Comment: I want to create a folder name valid which contains folder name as 0607130001 but last 20 files from train 0607130001/ should be in valid folder...                              
  valid                                                                               
      0607130001/0607130001-31.png......0607130001-50.png

Comment: Can you create something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699059/representing-directory-file-structure-in-markdown-syntax) for input and output?