# How should I upload full-stack project to github, with existing .git file in backend folder?

Tags: git, github

I have completed and deployed a project on Heroku and had to create a git repository to host the backend.

a .git folder exists in my server folder, but now I would like to take my client and my server folder and upload them together onto github.

If I just cd into the project folder and run "git init" only my client folder is highlighted. I know that the .git folder in my server folder is the reason for this, but I am unsure of how to proceed. Please advise.

p.s. for the record I followed along with this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aibtHnbeuio).

Comment: Could you add a [folder diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699059/representing-directory-file-structure-in-markdown-syntax) to better represent both of the folders?

Comment: You can mv your existing .git folder into a safe place somewhere else.