# How to disable Nuxt's inbuilt error handling?

Tags: nginx, error-handling, nuxt.js, production, nuxtjs3

Nuxt error handling works excellent locally, but it causes some issues in production. I'm looking for a way to completely disable Nuxt's inbuilt error handling; I created a custom error page that is redirected by Nginx configuration.

Right now when you're being redirected to the error page, nuxt's default error message is being presented together with the custom error page I created; here's an image:
[image]
[image]

I tried searching online, but all I found were some 'hacks' and unorthodox ways to solve this problem.

Is there a clean, better way to disable Nuxt error handling? Is there a way to disable Nuxt's default message?

Comment: @kissu No problem, I will. I updated the answer for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem solved by doing those changes:

---

1. Add this `generate` line into your `nuxt.config.js`:

```
generate: { fallback: '404.html' }
```

You can read about it here: [Nuxt - The generate Property](https://You%20can%20read%20about%20it%20here:%20%5BNuxt%20-%20The%20generate%20Property%5D%5B1%5D).

---

2. Insert your `error.vue` file into the `pages` folder. Don't include a subfolder called error, don't create a subfolder at all. Just place it inside as he is. It should be treated as a page.

```
website
 ┣ assets
 ┣ components
 ┣ layouts
 ┣ modules
 ┗ pages
   ┣ about
   ┣ use-cases
   ┣ error.vue  <---
   ┗ index.vue
```

---

3. Add a basic layout to your `layouts` folder. If you don't have a `layouts` folder, create one. I recommend understanding how layouts work in Nuxt: [Nuxt - Layouts directory](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/layouts/).

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Damn, how did you generated this kind of structure (with the folders)? Using a specific website or doing by hand?

Comment: @kissu This is my first time creating a folder structure, so I just googled `stackoverflow folder structure` which brought me to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57086391/17718587). I created this structure by hand, but there seems to be an extension doing precisely that; I didn't test it out yet.